# Providing an algorithm which executes with O(nlogn) to solve the following problem

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Write an O(n lg n) algorithm that receives as input an array A of n real numbers  sorted in non-decreasing order and a value, val. The algorithm returns true if there are distinct indexes i and j such that a[i] + a[j] = val and false otherwise.

I figured the following pseudo code but realized it only works for neighboring elements

```
checkArray(Array A, val)    
if  A.length==2        
if A[0] + A[1] =val
return true;        
else  
return false       
else   
L1 = checkArray (A[0 : n/2],val) 
L2 = checkArray(A[n/2 : n], val)
```

Comment: Hint: for each `i` check if there is a `j` that makes `a[i] + a[j] = val`.

Comment: By the way, it is also possible to come up with an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: @Henry: In case of `O(n)` time algorithm we want `O(n)` space as well.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I think we can have O(1) space using 2 pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hints in the comments pretty much give away the `O(nlogn)` answer- iterate over each element `a[i]`, and do a binary search on the array to see if `val - a[i]` exists. I'm not going to go into further detail about this algorithm, since it seems fairly straightforward. Instead, I'd like to shine some light on the `O(n)` solution, which may not be so obvious.

In short, the `O(n)` uses two pointers that will work their way from the ends towards the middle, constantly checking if the two sum to `val`. If their sum is larger than `val`, we decrease the larger of the two (the rightmost pointer) by moving its pointer one to the left. If its smaller, we increase the smaller of the two by moving its pointer right. If the two pointers pass each other, we know that no solution exists.

```
checkArray(Array A, val)
    indexLo = 0
    indexHi = len(A) - 1
    while indexLo <= indexHi
        sum = A[indexLo] + A[indexHi]
        if sum == val
            return True

        if sum < val
            indexLo += 1
        else
            indexHi -= 1
    return False
```

Comment: @qova glad to hear. If this post answers your question, feel free to accept it.